# What is the syntax for using the color property of a class in an "if...then" statement

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicolor

I have a program in which depending on where I touch the screen, it will make a square turn red or blue. But based on what color the square is, I want to have a specific set of rules. I'm trying to write a code that basically states if the square color is red...do this, or if the square color is blue... do that. The square is in its' own class and I'm using a setter/getter method named setColor in order to change it's color from the ViewController class. When writing the "if then" rule, I can't write "if (cv.color == blueColor) {do something...}". Does anyone know what the proper syntax would be in this situation?

Comment: If you have a getter, what stops you writing `if (cv.GetColor() == blueColor) { bla bla }`'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare colors:

```
if ([cv.color isEqual:[UIColor blueColor]]) {
    // it's blue
} else if ([cv.color isEqual:[UIColor redColor]]) {
    // it's red
}
```

Comment: I've figured out what i need to do, I didn't create a color property in the square (cv)class. As usual the problem has a simple answer.